# XML Parsing at 64 bit browser

Tags: java, xml, internet-explorer, firefox, dom

I have to parse the xml file and it is done well if I have used any of the 32 bit Firefox, but not working well at 64 bit browser. I have used the DOM Parsing in java program. Would be any difference? 
The error as follows

SAX Exception : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.I have searched the problem in net and somebody said add a space between utf-8 and the prolog.I have tried that too. But still the problem exist. 
Please suggest me about the real problem.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you have an actual problem, what exactly are you asking here?

Comment: The system shows SAXParserException

Comment: Please edit your question so the actual problem will be displayed and add some logs

Comment: Content is not allowed in prolog is almost certainly a UTF8 BOM issue. You are not allowed anything between the start of the file and the first opening brace, but your parser is interpreting the BOM as a character, rather than a marker